# When creating new element in jQuery, is there a method that is faster?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way that has better performance than the other when appending a new element to the dom with jQuery?

This is the way I usually do it:

```
$('<div class="foo">Hello World!</div>').appendTo($("#bar"));
```

But I've seen this quite a few times around :

```
$('<div/>').attr("class", "foo").text("Hello World!").appendTo($("#bar"));
```

I think that the first one is easier to read. Second one takes advantage of chaining but it in the end, the result is the same. But is it faster to do it one way of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/SvCTK/

the difference in performance is pretty trivial (maybe not that trivial, find out for yourself). Source for benchmark:

```
var loop = 1000,
    $bar = $('#bar');

console.time('first')
while(loop--){
    $('<div class="foo">Hello World!</div>').appendTo($bar);
}
console.timeEnd('first');

loop = 1000;
$bar.html('');

console.time('second')
while(loop--){
   $('<div/>').attr("class", "foo").text("Hello World!").appendTo($bar);
}
console.timeEnd('second');
```

You need a open `FireBug` or `Webkit developers tools` to see the results.

Comment: It's about a 50% difference for me. I don't know if I'd call that trivial. Also, as another note, as of jQuery 1.4.2 I think it was, you can do this: `$('<div>',{class: 'foo',text:'Hello World!'})`

Comment: On my side the difference was 240ms so that is 0.24ms for one call. As you say, the difference in performance is trivial. Is it considered best practice to do it one way or the other ?

Comment: @Jamie, @Gabriel: Well for me it was only little veriance between the two, might be the poor system I'm currently at.

Comment: @Jamie: the way you suggested is working too. But I used jAndy's script to time it and it takes longer than the one with .attr(). So it seems that writing the full string for the tag, attributes and text is faster...

Comment: @Gabriel: It obviously must be a little bit faster, but when **really** concerning about performance, you shouldn't use jQuery at all. Go with `document.createElement()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is faster because it does not have to deal with extra call of `attr` function.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are fine, however the first will be a little quicker due to it using less methods. So instead of just using .appendTo you are using .attr, .text, and .appendTo.

Answer (score 0):

You comparison isn't quiet accurate.  If your code was adding attribute values to targeted elements then you'd have the same number of function calls.  I'm pretty sure they are equivalent approaches.

Editorial:

JQuery is written using the concept of a fluent interface which is what enables the chaining of method calls.  It is equivalent code as writing each step out in a more step-by-step way.

Answer (score 0):

`document.createElement()` is technically the fastest method to create DOM elements. However, the amount of time saved is typically trivial.

```
$(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr('class', 'foo')
    .text("Hello World!")
    .appendTo("#bar");
```